# Rearrange 2d list

Tags: python, list

I have a rather easy problem, but still can't come up with a solution.
I have two 2d lists:

```
a = [('0', '1'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '4'), ('1', '3')]
b = [('3', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('3', '2'), ('4', '2')]
```

Now I want to get all elements, which are the same in both lists.

```
both = set(a) & set(b)
print(both)
```

This code however only works if the elements are in the same order. So (3, 1) ≠ (1, 3).
I tried to change the index:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if (a[i][0]) > (a[b][1]):
        order = [1,0]
        a = [a[i] for j in order]
    else:
        break
```

But this did nothing. Is there an easy way to change the order, so the lower number is alwas the first?

Comment: “so the lower number is alwas the first”. What about sorting? Granted an increased overhead, but quick thought.

Answer (score 0):

You may sort each tuple before

```
result = set([tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in a]) & \
         set([tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in b])

print(result)  # {('1', '3'), ('2', '4')}
```